# This was working earlier but now I get Compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a new macro earlier and it was working fine but now I get this error. I have not changed anything including the columns or worksheet name, any ideas why it's erroring now? The row that is highlighted in yellow when I try to debug it is:Columns("L:L").Select.

```
Sub FTE_Joiners()

 FTE_Joiners Macro

Sheets("Joiners").Select
Columns("L:L").Select
Range("L2").Activate
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"".""0""""0"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce that to

```
Sheets("Joiners").Columns("L:L").NumberFormat = "0"".""0""""0"
```

There's nothing in what you've told us that would suggest a problem.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).